# keep value after post razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

this is my page

```
@page
@model ServiceHost.Pages.AccountModel
<div class="page-content-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="page-wrapper">
                    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                                @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Shared/Account/LoginForm", Model.LoginForm);};
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                                @{
                                    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Shared/Account/RegisterForm", Model.RegisterForm);
                                };
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using _0_Framework.Application;
using _0_Framework.Infrastructure;
using AccountManagement.Application.Contract.Account;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace ServiceHost.Pages
{
    public class AccountModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IAccountApplication _accountApplication;
        private readonly IAuthHelper _authHelper;
      
        public LoginModel LoginForm { get; set; } = new LoginModel();

        public AccountRegisterModel RegisterForm { get; set; } = new AccountRegisterModel();

        public AccountModel(IAccountApplication accountApplication, IAuthHelper authHelper)
        {
            _accountApplication = accountApplication;
            _authHelper = authHelper;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostLogin(LoginModel command)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               return page();
            }
            var result = _accountApplication.Login(command);
            if (result.IsSuccedded)
            {
                return Redirect("./Index");
            }
            LoginMessage = result.Message;
            return RedirectToPage("./Account");
        }
    }
}
```

i want if user result is return RedirectToPage("./Account"); kept inputs value in form for user to user don't need to enter input again

this is my partial login form

```
@model AccountManagement.Application.Contract.Account.LoginModel

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Login">

    <div class="login-form">
        <h4 class="login-title">ورود</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-12">
                <label asp-for="UserName">نام کاربری</label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="نام کاربری">
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <label asp-for="Password">رمز عبور</label>
                <input type="password" asp-for="Password" name="Password" placeholder="رمز عبور">
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-left text-sm-right">
                <a href="#" class="forget-pass-link">رمز خود را فراموش کرده اید ؟</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button class="register-button">ورود</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

what i need to do for this
how can i send a login model in on get
i try to [bindProperty] but got trouble in validate the validation message showed before user enter any thing in i don't like this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return current page  and keep the input text without error message
Try  replace

```
return RedirectToPage("./Account");
```

with

```
    ModelState.Clear();
    return Page();
```

If I misunderstand your requirement,please point it out

Comment: i want to had error massage but input don't missed to user need to input again

Comment: do you mean the password input would be null when you reach the page again,and you want to keep the passwod here?

Comment: Password field would be cleared when postback due to security reason,it just  performed as designed

Comment: i mean to kept userName